# Missing personalization rules around GeoIP

Tags: personalization, rules-engine, geo-location

I'm trying to set up and test GeoIP personalization rules in a Sitecore 9 instance. However, when I go to personalize a page or component, the GeoIP section of the rules is missing.

I've compared this to a vanilla install, and the rules are definitely there. I did a side-by-side comparison, and the only rules sections that look different are GeoIP and Visit/Visitor (they're named/organized differently, despite being the same Sitecore 9 version).

This site was a new install, and wasn't an upgrade. Any idea why these GeoIP rules aren't there for use? Could this be a configuration issue? In the \App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.Tracking\Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config file, I've set Analytics.PerformLookup to true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had this issue yesterday. The problem is that if you have tracking disabled on your CM instance, there is a visibility rule that prevents the whole section from showing up. This means that even if you have tracking enable on your CD instance, it won't show up on your CM instance. The visibility rule is configured at `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/GeoIP/Visibility/Default`.

I'm not sure if it's the most supported way, but I just backed up that item, deleted it, cleared the cache, and the rules appeared again. If clearing the cache isn't enough, you may need to recycle the app pool as well.

I *normally* don't advocate deleting an internal item. The alternative would be to modify `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Tracking/Tracking Enabled` to use your own class and to use different logic for deciding if tracking is enabled, but you would still be modifying a Sitecore item. Or you could open a ticket with Sitecore to ask for a patch. Up to you.

Comment: Thank you. Is `Analytics.PerformLookup ` the only tracking that needs to be enabled? Once enabled on both CD and CM, I should see the GeoIP rules? Also, do you know if the rules will remain hidden until you activate a GeoIP subscription?

Comment: It looks for `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` to be set to `true` on the CM server.